# How can I solve: $\begin{cases} 5x - y = 2 \\ 4y^2 + 4xy - 4x^2 - 1 = 0 \\ \end{cases}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve this:
$$\begin{cases}
 5x - y = 2 \\
4y^2 + 4xy - 4x^2 - 1 = 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

I did this, it starts like \begin{equation} x = \frac {2+y}{5} ------- (3) \end{equation}

right?

then,

\begin{equation} 4y^2 + 4 \left( \frac {2+y}{5}\ \right)y - 4 \left( \frac {2+y}{5}\right)^2 - 1 = 0  \end{equation}

\begin{equation} 4y^2 + \left( \frac {8+4y}{5}\ \right)y - 4  \left(\frac {2^2+4y+y^2}{25}\ \right) - 1 = 0  \end{equation}

It then becomes complicated! what next?

Comment: ehm... do the math and simplify?

Comment: Use the substitution $y=5x-2$ instead, it will avoid you the hassle with fractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get
$$
y=5x-2
$$
so
$$
4(5x-2)^2+4x(5x-2)-4x^2-1=0
$$
this simplify to 
$$
116x^2-88x+15=0
$$
Then you can solve your quadratic equation.

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically, the solutions are the intersection *points* of the line $5x-y=2$ and the hyperbola $4(5x-2)^2 + 4x(5x-2)-4x^2-1=0$.

[image]

The stratergy goes as follows:

1. Solve the linear equation (the one without powers) for either $x$ ot $y$.
2. Substitute this in to the non-linear equation (the one with the powers).
3. Expand, bring everything to the same side, collect like terms.
4. Solve the resulting equation, in this case it's a quadratic.
5. Use these values for $x$ (resp. $y$) to find the corresponding values for $y$ (resp. $x$).
6. Pair your solutions together.

In your case we have:

1. Solve $5x-y=2$. It's easiest to get $y=5x-2$.
2. Putting this into $4y^2+4xy-4x^2-1=0$ gives $4(5x-2)^2 + 4x(5x-2)-4x^2-1=0$.
3. Expanding gives $116x^2-88x+15=0$.
4. We can solve by factorisation: $(58x-15)(2x-1)=0$, so $x=\frac{15}{58}$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}$.
5. When $x=\frac{15}{58}$ we have $y=5\left(\tfrac{15}{58}\right)-2=-\frac{41}{48}$. When $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $y=5\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)-2=\frac{1}{2}$
6. The solutions are $(x,y)=\left(\tfrac{15}{58},-\tfrac{41}{48}\right)$ and $(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$